# How to let JS code allow both input and textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some JS code that will turn my code bold, italicized, or underlined with user input, so if the user checks bold the text will be bolded.
Here is the code:

```js
$('input[name="textStyle"]').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == 'bold'){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('input[name="styledText"]').css('font-weight', 'bold');
            else $('input[name="styledText"]').css('font-weight', 'normal');
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'italic'){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('input[name="styledText"]').css('font-style', 'italic');
            else $('input[name="styledText"]').css('font-style', 'normal');
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'underline'){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('input[name="styledText"]').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
            else $('input[name="styledText"]').css('text-decoration', 'none');
        }
    });
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #5f5959;
    color: #000000;
}
textarea[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: 000000;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

textarea[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #908989;
}

div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; color: #f9f9f9;">
    Bold:<input name="textStyle" type="checkbox" value="bold"/>
    <br>
    Italic:<input name="textStyle" type="checkbox" value="italic"/>
    <br>
    Underline:<input name="textStyle" type="checkbox" value="underline"/>
</form>

<div style="margin-left: 240px; width: 1000px; height: 665px;">
    <p><center style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">When submit, your text will clear and your blog will be published!</center></p>
    <textarea type="text" placeholder="Title" style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;"></textarea>
    <form style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;">
        <textarea name="styledText" type="text" style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; outline: none; border: none; height: 445px;"></textarea>
        <input style="height: 50px; width: 1000px; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; border-radius: 7px;" value="Submit" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

It is giving me an error, and it is not bolding/italicized/underlined. I think this is because the JS code is checking for input, but the tag is textarea. Is there any way I can let it accept both? I want the large area that is blank to be bolded/italicized/underlined with user input. Thanks!

Comment: You could query for the `textarea`? `$('textarea[name=styledText]')`

Comment: If you want jQuery to check for two selectors in one the same function, you could use ````$('input[name="styledText"], textarea[name="styledText"]')````  or even ````$('[name="styledText"]')````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First instead of `$('input[name="styledText"]')` you should do `$('textarea[name="styledText"]')`. Secondly jquery `.css` also accepts an object, so create an object `cssProps` and add default properties. Then on toggling of the check box change the value of these keys. Once it is done then at the end use `.css` and pass the `cssProps` properties

```js
let cssProps = {
  'font-weight': '',
  'font-style': '',
  'text-decoration': ''
}

$('input[name="textStyle"]').change(function() {
  const val = $(this).val()
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    switch (val) {
      case 'bold':
        cssProps['font-weight'] = 'bold';
        break;
      case 'italic':
        cssProps['font-style'] = 'italic';
        break;
      case 'underline':
        cssProps['text-decoration'] = 'underline';
        break;
    }
  } else {
    switch (val) {
      case 'bold':
        cssProps['font-weight'] = '';
        break;
      case 'italic':
        cssProps['font-style'] = '';
        break;
      case 'underline':
        cssProps['text-decoration'] = '';
        break;

    }
  }
  $('textarea[name="styledText"]').css(cssProps)
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #5f5959;
  color: #000000;
}

textarea[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: 000000;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

textarea[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #908989;
}

div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; color: #f9f9f9;">
  Bold:<input name="textStyle" type="checkbox" value="bold" />
  <br> Italic:
  <input name="textStyle" type="checkbox" value="italic" />
  <br> Underline:
  <input name="textStyle" type="checkbox" value="underline" />
</form>

<div style="margin-left: 240px; width: 1000px; height: 665px;">
  <p>
    <center style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">When submit, your text will clear and your blog will be published!</center>
  </p>
  <textarea type="text" placeholder="Title" style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;"></textarea>
  <form style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;">
    <textarea name="styledText" type="text" style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; outline: none; border: none; height: 445px;"></textarea>
    <input style="height: 50px; width: 1000px; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; border-radius: 7px;" value="Submit" type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`$('[name="styledText"]')` will access all tags with `name="styledText"`

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have used `textarea` element instead of `input` in javascript code becuase you used `textarea` as a field.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/o1msuL83/

Answer (score -1):

Please refer below link. I have made one change in your HTML `<textarea type="text" name="styledText" placeholder="Title" style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;"></textarea>`. Also I have target `name` attribute like `$('[name="styledText"]')`.

https://codepen.io/Umesh8965/pen/jOymyLo